# Interstellar in In-Flight Entertainment

Tags: air-travel, entertainment

Has the movie Interstellar been added to the database for in-flight entertainment on any flights yet? In other words, if I wanted to board a flight just to watch Interstellar, could I do that? If so, where?

Comment: Note that there is typically no guarantee that the monitor in the seat in front of yours will be operating correctly. Likewise, equipment changes happen all the time - replacement planes may have no in-flight entertainment. When additionally taking into account carbon emission, it appears most resonable for you to either (1) watch it in cinema (if they still have it), or (2) wait for it to appear on disc.

Comment: I've never seen a film available on a plane while it was still showing in cinemas

Comment: Why the downvotes, people?

Comment: Interesting method of choosing a destination....

Comment: While I don't plan to watch Interstellar, I would like to know more about the releasing of movies on in-flight entertainment, so upvoting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you want to watch a great movie strapped to a uncomfortable seat, while the person in front of you reclines his seat and crushes your feet, on a small crappy screen, interrupted by PA announcements, with babies crying, people coughing and farting and constant engine sound in the background.

The answer is no, not yet. You have to wait a few more months, maybe a year until its out of cinemas and then you get to fulfill your dream

Comment: Wrong, many airlines purchase the movies and show them in that period when the movie leaves the theaters and before it is on DVDs, the same period where the movies can be purchased on the so called "home cinemas" in cable networks. It is a great way for movie makers to get some extra bucks in this period from airlines actually.

Comment: You said that airlines buy movies when they leave the theathers. Which is exactly what I said. What are we arguing about? :)

Comment: I said, after they leave the theaters _and before they are on DVDs_, that is most likely to be less than a year AFAIK

Comment: Actually I was reading the comment in the question which says to wait for it to be on disc, then read your answer, mixed the two in my head and replied accordingly :) so your answer is right.

Comment: There are crying babies, farts and coughs in a film hall too :( 1080p (preferably a pirated copy)  + load of Nutella is my kind of heaven. Airline sites often advertise their in-flight entertainment (Malaysia Airlines for example). But from what I've seen, films get added to IFE when they are done in theaters.